# angular js path returns 404 error when https is used

Tags: angularjs, https

Please keep in mind, I have not worked with angular JS, nor did I write the code that is causing the error.

I am getting an 404 error on this path:

https://www.helivalues.com/Su6UsWuf/bb/option/mfg/all

but not this path:

http://www.helivalues.com/Su6UsWuf/bb/option/mfg/all

It was noticed that when a user views a certain page in https, the drop down does not load options. Angular Js makes a call to the path mention above which is not an actually file but is used by a php file that based on this path, has a switch that fills in the drop down.

Any ideas on how to get the https version to work? This is on a joomla site and I do have access to the htaccess file if needed. I really just need it to work for a few months while I work on building a new site.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs is not the issue. Your webserver (Apache/2.2.15 (SuSE) Server at www.helivalues.com Port 443) states the file can not be found. So it looks like something is misconfigured with your apache site.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but this server is being hosted on rackspace and they setup the ssl. It was not configured in the apache config file, so I am unsure how it was setup. I did put in a ticket with them about the issue yesterday but rackspace says it is something with the htaccess file.

Comment: @ChristineGregory the point still is that it is not angularjs but something on the server side.